# How to capture time of request in SOAP UI?

Tags: groovy, soapui

I'm using SOAP UI to decide which response to send based on the time I receive the request message - basically, I have a time tag in my response messages. I send the response with the time tag that has the greatest value that is still less than the time the request was received.

I've found lots of information on how to measure the time taken for a message exchange, but none on how to simply determine what time the request was received. Help? Thanks.

Comment: Not sure I understand--if you're receiving the request can't you just note at what time you received it?

Comment: This isn't something I can do manually. This MockService will be used with an app that is sending requests. I need to capture the time the request was received in order to decide upon the right response.

Comment: Where do you need it? In Mock service?

Comment: I need to have this information available in the MockOperation dispatch script. In this script, I'll get the time of request, choose the right response, and return this response.

Comment: You can create date object at the beginning of dispatch script.

Comment: Ok, how does one go about this?